# VBA Excel Fill Down on multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba, autofill

Hi I could not find the answer to my question from searching.

I have multiple worksheets and would like to create a column at the very beginning with a fill-down type approach of a specific string.

For example,

If worksheet name contains "Zebra" - insert a new column at the very beginning and input "Zebra's" across all cells down up until the last data point on the adjacent column.

I need to do this for four different worksheets:
Zebra
Elephant
Rhino
Snake

```
Here is what I have thus far, I cannot get it to work:

Sub addAnimal()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim N As Long

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
If ws.Name Like "zebra*" Then

Application.Goto ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ws.Name).Cells(2, 1)
ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Insert

ActiveCell.Value = "Zebra"

Dim lastRow As Long, lastUsedRow As Long
Dim srcRange As Range, fillRange As Range
With Worksheets(ws.Name)
    lastUsedRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lastRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ' Fill values from A:D all the way down to lastUsedRow

    Set srcRange = .Range("A" & lastUsedRow)
    Set fillRange = .Range("A" & lastRow)

    fillRange.Value = srcRange.Value
End With

End If
Next ws
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the array of animals compared to the collection of worksheet names there is going to be some repetition but a helper sub procedure can eliminate much of it.

```
Option Explicit

Sub addAnimalMain()
    Dim w As Long, grr As Variant

    grr = Array("Zebra", "Elephant", "Rhino", "Snake")

    For w = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(w)
            Select Case True
                Case CBool(InStr(1, .Name, grr(0), vbTextCompare))
                    addAnimalHelper ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(w), grr(0)
                Case CBool(InStr(1, .Name, grr(1), vbTextCompare))
                    addAnimalHelper ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(w), grr(1)
                Case CBool(InStr(1, .Name, grr(2), vbTextCompare))
                    addAnimalHelper ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(w), grr(2)
                Case CBool(InStr(1, .Name, grr(3), vbTextCompare))
                    addAnimalHelper ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(w), grr(3)
            End Select
        End With
    Next w
End Sub

Sub addAnimalHelper(ws As Worksheet, grrr As Variant)
    With ws
        .Columns(1).EntireColumn.Insert
        .Range(.Cells(1, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(0, -1)) = grrr
    End With
End Sub
```